# Could passing Context to a static helper method as an argument potentially cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, android

I have a helper class that consists of various static methods, one of those methods requires Context to access some information. Could passing Context to a static helper method as an argument potentially cause a memory leak?

```
public class ConnectionHelper {
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm != null;
    }
}
```

How does the static method behave, does it dispose of the context reference after it has executed or will it hang around in memory afterward?

Comment: why should it leak memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you do with the `Context` reference passed in.

If you store the reference indefinitely, it will leak. Nothing really to do with `static`-ness. (Though accidentally storing references for too long is easy with static *variables*.)

The code you posted does not store references anywhere outside the method's scope and does not leak.

Comment: How to store the reference?

Comment: You store a reference by writing it to some variable. The variables in the question's code have method scope and do not live any longer than the method is running.

Comment: It is not me who posted the question, but can u give an example, I'm new to java?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you provide, doesn't store anything, so it won't leak.

But in generally it could lead to a memory leak, if you pass an Activiy and store it.
Then the whole Activity with all views, images and everything would not get garbage collected.

You'll have to take care to only pass an Application Context.

Comment: If you don't _store_ the activity, there's no leak related to calling a static method with it.

Comment: if under the same conditions (static method(from Utility java class , passing an activity context to it ) to store  some value in shared preference , because shared pefs  need some contextual reference to access it.
would this static method  leak the activity context ?